# Multiple values for an AND/OR statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Is it possible to combine `AND` (or `OR`) statement criteria to avoid repeating a cell name?

For example, I want to see if cell C2 contains the any of the numbers 2,3,5,7, or 10. I want to avoid writing

```
IF(AND(C2=2,C2=3... etc.
```

and simplify it to an array of the numbers like

```
IF(AND(C2=[2,3,5,7,10]...
```

Unfortunately, I have a lot more than just 5 numbers to add so it's getting be very laborious. Anyone have an easier way than repeating the cell name=__ over and over?

Answer (score 4):

You can use an "array constant" like this

`=IF(OR(C2={2,3,5,7,10}),"Yes","No")`

.....or for a large set of numbers you could put all the numbers in a cell range, e.g. `Z2:Z100` and do the same

`=IF(OR(C2=$Z$2:$Z$100),"Yes","No")`

although when you use a range rather than an array constant the formula becomes an "array formula" so needs to be confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

perhaps better to use `COUNTIF` and avoid "array entering"...

`=IF(COUNTIF($Z$2:$Z$100,C2)>0,"Yes","No")`

Comment: That helps a lot, thanks. I have a list of about 100 alpha-numeric codes. Certain rows need to fit the criteria of certain codes, so using an array constant will do me a lot of good here.

Answer (score 3):

`=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(C2,{2,3,5,7,11},0)),"no","yes")`

No need to enter this as an array formula. How it works: `MATCH` returns a `#N/A!` error if it can't find the lookup value in the lookup array. `ISERROR` catches this.

But as [barry houdini suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29258078/119775), you may want to put your numbers in some range e.g. Z1:Z5 instead of hard-coding them into your formula. So you would have this formula instead:

`=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(C2,Z1:Z5,0)),"no","yes")`

Comment: MATCH is a good way - I usually use `ISNUMBER` then you can show the positive value first! This reminds me - if you can use `ISNUMBER(MATCH` you can use `COUNTIF` too - better than `SUMPRODUCT`.....

Comment: @barryhoudini: Right, but that would require me to type 1 more character.

Comment: Well, if it character count is king try `ISNA`!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett thanks for the edit, and the advice on ISNUMBER. Big help.