# Sum one column if number not in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

The following formula should return 15 in each of the cells `E3:E6`. It should sum column labeled X but not include any numbers in this sum if they are found in column `D`.

Note: no additional helper columns are allowed, but the `Total` cells `C8:D8` can be used.

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to duplicate identical information in four different cells?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett why shouldn't I want to?

Comment: I'm just curious. Usually you don't want to have duplicate information lying around for no reason. But maybe you do have a reason.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett to be honest I've added this question for a colleague - she usually only does stuff if required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNA(MATCH($C$3:$C$6,$D$3:$D$6,0))*$C$3:$C$6)
```

[image]

`MATCH` returns an `#N/A!` error when it can't find the lookup value (X) in the lookup array (Y). `ISNA()` converts matches to `FALSE` and non-matches (`#N/A!`) to `TRUE`. When multiplied using the mathematical operator `*`, `TRUE` becomes 1 and `FALSE` becomes 0. `SUMPRODUCT` finally sums up the X's that line up with 1's (and not those with 0's).

Comment: slight variant on your answer: `=SUMPRODUCT(1*ISNA(MATCH($C$3:$C$6,$D$3:$D$6,0)),$C$3:$C$6)`

Comment: `SUMPRODUCT` takes arrays as inputs, but spits out a single value — so it's a way to avoid array formulas.

Comment: I see that - also you have used Match in an array-like way with the first argument being an array - not seen that before: thanks

Comment: Other examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29558629/sumifs-with-criterion-not-in-range/29558968#29558968 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29258010/multiple-values-for-an-and-or-statement/29258426#29258426

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
=DSUM($C$3:$D$6;1;$D$3:$D$6)
```